# JavaScript Regex does not match exact string

Tags: javascript, regex, match, exact-match

In the example below the output is true. It `cookie` and it also matches `cookie14214` I'm guessing it's because cookie is in the string `cookie14214`. How do I hone-in this match to only get `cookie`?

```
var patt1=new RegExp(/(biscuit|cookie)/i);
document.write(patt1.test("cookie14214"));
```

Is this the best solution?

```
var patt1=new RegExp(/(^biscuit$|^cookie$)/i);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on your allowance of characters surrounding the word `cookie`. If the word is to appear strictly on a line by itself, then:

```
var patt1=new RegExp(/^(biscuit|cookie)$/i);
```

If you want to allow symbols (spaces, `.`, `,`, etc), but not alphanumeric values, try something like:

```
var patt1=new RegExp(/(?:^|[^\w])(biscuit|cookie)(?:[^\w]|$)/i);
```

Second regex, explained:

```
(?:                 # non-matching group
    ^               # beginning-of-string
    | [^\w]         # OR, non-alphanumeric characters
)

(biscuit|cookie)    # match desired text/words

(?:                 # non-matching group
    [^\w]           # non-alphanumeric characters
    | $              # OR, end-of-string
)
```

Comment: have you tested this? i dont think you can use the negative lookahead after the desired string.

Comment: @jbabey Yeah, tested with firebug; also, the regexes are not using any lookaheads (positive, or negative). The second one is using a non-matching group, `(?:`, if that's what you're confusing with `(?!`

Comment: @jbabey It's a good one to use; it works like it's name implies - the regex has to match that group also, but it doesn't return it in the list of matches. So, the return-array would only contain two groups (first is the "full context" of the match, second is the matched word).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, or use word boundaries. Note that this will match `great cookies` but not `greatcookies`.

```
var patt1=new RegExp(/(\bbiscuit\b|\bcookie\b)/i);
```

If you want to match the exact string `cookie`, then you don't even need regular expressions, just use `==`, since `/^cookie$/i.test(s)` is basically the same as `s.toLowerCase() == "cookie"`.